# Сдвиг рабочего пространства по событию

Tags: javascript, html

Всем доброго времени суток!
Вторые сутки ищу решение, пока к сожалению так и не смог найти..

Ситуация такая, есть рабочее пространство position: fixed; width, height - 100% (в нем всякие блоки), блоки установлены по координатам x, y.

Возникает вопрос, как по событию mousemove сдвигать рабочее пространство без изменения координат, как это присходит в онлайн-браузерных играх?

Comment: @UModeL они и так абсолютные, но как мне сдвигать именно? банально css({left: ..., top: ...})?

Comment: Разницу между _абсолютным_ и _относительным_ понимаете? И зачем Вам _fixed_ , если  хотите _mousemove_?

Comment: Можете попробовать использовать css - `transform: translate(X, Y);`

Comment: @UModeL понимаю)) но есть возможность как-то сдвинуть блоки без потери координат? координаты записаны в базе

Comment: 1) margin-left, margin-top; 2) через изменение ширины\высоты :before :after у карты; 3) обернуть это пространство в родителя и двигать родителя

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо, кто пытался помочь! С сохранением координат получилось так, сделал как в онлайн браузерной игре:
1. Задаем фиксированную ширину и высоту.
2. Задаем для данного блока overflow: Hidden (чтобы скрыть скроллы), в моем случае так же и на Canvas задаем те же размеры, position; relative.
3. На события mousedown -> mousemove -> mouseup скролим в зависимости от mousemove!